# How to use a fixed color for the stat_ellipse while having grouped data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ellipse

I would like to set just one color for the ellipses plotted but when I provide a single color (`stat_ellipse(color="black")`) or a separate color per ellipse, to `stat_ellipse`, outside the `aes()` (`stat_ellipse(color=ellipses_colors)`), I only get a single ellipse and not an ellipse per group per panel of the grid.

```
d <- data.frame(

    value1 = value_in_dimension_1,
    value2 = value_in_dimension_2,
    feature1 = dimension_1,
    feature2 = dimension_2,
    type = cluster_of_point
)


ggplot(d, aes(value1, value2, color=type)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_ellipse() +
    facet_grid(feature1 ~ feature2)
```

The results, when using `stat_ellipse()`:

[image]

The results, when using `stat_ellipse(color=ellipses_colors)` or `stat_ellipse(color="black")`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `group` aesthetic and set it to the type:

```
ggplot(d, aes(value1, value2, color=type)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_ellipse(aes(group = type), colour = "black") +
    facet_grid(feature1 ~ feature2)
```